# Resizing TableViewCell to suit RSS Feed Detail

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview

I'm working on an RSS Feed and I'm looking at resizing the TableViewCell to suit the Title/Description information that comes in, I'd like the Cell to show all the text rather than cut it off... Does anybody know a good way of doing this or know of a good tutorial?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: can you please explain me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the height for the cell holding your feed item data and return it when the table asks for it in [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Furthermore you need to say the `UILabel` not to truncate your text. For this, check out the methods under [Sizing the Label’s Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should make custom UITableViewCell for that.Then set it correct autosizing parameters in your .xib file
And then, in your cell .m file you should implement layoutSubviews method in such way

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect newFrame = rssLabel.frame;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(rssLabel.frame.size.width,9999);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [rssLabel.text sizeWithFont:tweetLabel.font        constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:rssLabel.lineBreakMode];
    int height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    newFrame.size.height = height;
    rssLabel.frame = newFrame;
}
```

And surely, I forgot to say that you should calculate the height of your row

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to subclass `UITableViewCell`. In this class implement a class method to return you height of cell. in tableview's delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` call this method and pass your text to it. Use `NSString's`  `sizeWithFont` `constrainedToSize` `lineBreakMode`: method and calcilate height. set your label's property `noOfLines` to 0. And you're good to go.

For example:-

```
+(CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString *)value{
     CGSize size = [value sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, MAXFLOAT)];
     if(size.height<MINIMUM_CELL_HEIGHT){
         return MINIMUM_CELL_HEIGHT;
     }else{
    return size.height;
     }
 }
```